# Can't disable (set to read-only, protect, gray-out etc.) a field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I've run this code:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("subject").setValue("Beep");;
alert(Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("subject").setDisabled);
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("subject").setDisabled(true);
```

As expected, I get the text *Beep* into the field. As expected, the alert tells me the contents of the method (and as far I can tell, they're doing what they're supposed to).

However, the Control itself doesn't get disabled. What am I doing wrong?

I believe that I saw **one** example of different approach (something more between *get* and *setDisabled* but after a few hours of googling, I'm starting to conclude that I must've been halucinating or wish-thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, so it should be working. The syntax used by @Daryl is correct to. Those two lines are equivalent. The shorter one is just syntactic sugar shortening the other. So, you should use his.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("subject").setDisabled(true);
Xrm.Page.getControl("subject).setDisabled(true);
```

If you're alerting out and getting the contents of the method, it means that you're hitting the right component and the correct method. Yet, so say that **despite** the call, the control doesn't get disabled. I think you're wrong.

Here's what I think happens. The control gets disabled, then, before you have time to notice it, the form get updated, rendering away your disable operation.

Keep in mind that **unlike the field data**, the property of being disabled doesn't get stored to the database. If you design a field as protected, it'll stay that way. But if you set such a property from the JavaScript code on the client-side, the appearance is only going to last until a reload of the page is performed.

So, if you need to keep the fields disabled, either make them so from the GUI designer or fire an *onLoad* method doing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I use the getControl function and it works fine.  should be in the form:

`Xrm.Page.getControl(controlId).setDisabled(disabled);`

And remember, disabled controls will not be updated unless you set the submit mode to "always".